# Jenkins git plugin - show file change at Changes menu

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to configure [Jenkins Git Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) to able to see the diff in files under the details in Changes menu. By now I can see only the list of the files which changed within a commit. The file list is click-able but inactive. So would be great to see the diff by clicking on the file.